# I get gradle sync error when adding Material Spinner 2.0.0(Unauthorized status 401)

Tags: android, gradle, spinner, lib, jitpack

This library was working fine last week but today it suddenly does not work
Even when I try to use version 1.1.2 and 1.1.1 , i have same error.
I received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

BELOW WHAT APPEARS ON THE GRADLE ANDROID STUDIO CONSOLE:

Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'.

Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'.

Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'.

Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'.

Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/ganfra/material-spinner/2.0.0/material-spinner-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Comment: Google for jitpack 401 errors

Comment: @StephenJ I went to his site and found many complaints from users and I preferred to change library. After all, I was only using Spinner. Thanks for the feedbac